# Save page data when leaving page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an edit form that that has 2 buttons on it, 'Save' (duh) and 'Return To List' ( which performs a save before actually returning ).  The problem is the page also has Side Navigation and Top Navigation. So when the user selects any link in those the page doesn't save.  Is there a way to perform a save even when Side or Top Navigation links are selected?

Note, this is an MVC3 C# project.

Comment: You can use an ajax call with the `onbeforeunload` javascript event. How are you currently saving data if the user clicks save?

Comment: The save gets executed as an HttpPost in the controller

Comment: That is exactly what I would like it to do. Thank you.  Can I accept a comment as the answer haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about just alerting the user the page hasn't saved yet? Use the `onbeforeunload` event, display an alert message (or something similar). If they want to save, have them click cancel to stay on the page and save, otherwise proceed without saving.